# Is this cast to subtype safe?

Tags: scala

Given these classes and variables:

```
abstract class Base[T <: Base[_]] {
  val self: T
  def me(): T = self
}

class Derived extends Base[Derived] {
  lazy val self = this
  def whoAmI() = "Im derived"
}

val d = new Derived
```

I can safely call `d.foo().whoAmI()`

But would this also be type safe?

```
abstract class Base[T <: Base[_]] {
  def me(): T = this.asInstanceOf[T]
}

class Derived extends Base[Derived] {
  def whoAmI() = "Im derived"
}
```

I'm thinking about edge cases in which other classes extend from Derived and the cast may blow up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't type safe. If you find you need to use `asInstanceOf` to make it compile, the answer will overwhelmingly be "No". The only time it is "safe" to cast to a sub-type is if there is only one sub-type. Otherwise, you cannot make any guarantees.

Consider this example:

```
abstract class Base[T <: Base[_]] {
  def me(): T = this.asInstanceOf[T]
}

class A extends Base[A]
class B extends Base[A]

scala> val b = new B
b: B = B@4b44655e

scala> b.me
java.lang.ClassCastException: B cannot be cast to A
  ... 33 elided
```

There is no restriction that the `T` in `Base` we're extending must be the same as the sub-type we are creating--only that they both extend `Base`. `A` and `B` are both a `Base[_]`, but a `B` is not an `A`, so casting to `A` would be unsafe.

This is easy to fix by introducing a self-type within `Base` that requires it is also a `T`. Then, we can be sure that `this` is a `T` and don't need to cast.

```
abstract class Base[T <: Base[_]] { this: T =>
  def me(): T = this
}
```

This will no longer compile:

```
scala> class B extends Base[A]
<console>:12: error: illegal inheritance;
 self-type B does not conform to Base[A]'s selftype A
       class B extends Base[A]
                       ^
```